# how to append elements in a list in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I have made a program that returns the number of a fibonacci series by using tail recursion, and I would like to add its results to a list. I have done the following:

```
(define listAux '())
(define (fibTail n1 n2 c)
  (if (= c 0)
      (appendList -1)
      (begin
        (appendList n2)
        (fibT (+ n1 n2) n1 (- c 1))
        )))

(define (appendList n)
  (if (= n -1)
      listAux
      (append (list n) listAux)))


(define (fib n)
  (fibTail 1 0 n))
```

I would like that appendList returns a list with the elements of the fibonacci series, when I call it like (fib 8) for example.
Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When programming in Lisp, we avoid using `append` for building lists - it's very inefficient because to insert a single element at the end, we have to traverse the whole list... and then again, and again. It's better to build the list in reverse order using `cons` and invert it at the end. Also, the ideal way of writing a tail recursion is to accumulate the results in a parameter, not in an externally defined variable (which anyway won't work, *unless* you `set!` its value somewhere). This is what I mean:

```
(define (fib n)
  (fibTail 1 0 n '()))

(define (fibTail n1 n2 c lst)
  (if (< c 0)
      (reverse lst)
      (fibTail (+ n1 n2) n1 (- c 1) (cons n2 lst))))
```

For example:

```
(fib 10)
=> '(0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55)
```